# Getting INVALID_ARGUMENT Error in quickSwap function

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, uniswap, polygon

I am trying to get `amountsOut` quote while swapping the USDT to USDC on polygon mainnet and getting a weird error even after doing the exact things that need to be done

```
  await window.ethereum.enable();
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
  const signer = provider.getSigner();

  const quickswap = new Contract("0xa5E0829CaCEd8fFDD4De3c43696c57F7D7A678ff", quickswapabi, signer);

  const path = ["0xc2132d05d31c914a87c6611c10748aeb04b58e8f", "0x2791bca1f2de4661ed88a30c99a7a9449aa84174"];

  const amountIn = ethers.utils.parseUnits("1", 6);

  const amountOut = await quickswap.getAmountsOut(amountIn, path);
```

While using this code I am getting this error

> Error: call revert exception [ See:
> https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ]
> (method="getAmountsOut(uint256,address[])", data="0x", errorArgs=null,
> errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION,
> version=abi/5.7.0)

I also tried to pass the value as a string and int but still its not working and giving this error

Comment: Can you add the value of path and quickswap? Best would be to share the whole code.

Comment: @NalLuksic added full code.

Comment: is this error given when you execute the transaction, or before you confirm the transaction, so while it tries to understand the gas price for the transaction? Cause I know Polygon has lots of problems with gas price estimation, thus you have to manually specify it

Comment: 1. Are you sure you are connected to Polygon mainnet? 2. Double-check if quickswapabi is correct. 3. Maybe try calling a view function like WETH() first to see if you have the correct contract instance.